# Find the missing result

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, enigmatic-puzzle

On a scrap of paper you read the following results:

> $$
> \begin{array}{r c l c}
> NETHERLANDS & - &FINLAND & 3-1 \\
> JAPAN & - &IRAQ & 0-0 \\
> RUSSIA & - &INDONESIA & 1-0 \\
> AUSTRALIA & - &CHINA & 0-1 \\
> CANADA & - &CUBA & 2-1 \\
> SWITZERLAND & - &FRANCE & 0-0 \\
> MADAGASCAR & - &EGYPT & 2-0 \\
> BRAZIL & - &BELGIUM & 5-1 \\
> IRELAND & - &GERMANY & 2-3 \\
> ALGERIA & - &COLOMBIA & 3-2 \\
> GREECE & - &MEXICO & ...
> \end{array}
> $$

Can you figure out what the result of Greece - Mexico should be?

Hint:

> I've written the countries' names in uppercase for a reason.

Hint 2:

> Most of these "results" have been the same for quite a while. One that has changed relatively recently is BRAZIL-BELGIUM, which used to be 0-1.

Comment: you forgot "Brazil  1 - 7 Germany".  Just saying.

Comment: I think that would be 1-2.

Comment: Er, no, wait, that's wrong; sorry.

Comment: Greece Mexico? Doesn't sound like a great game so I'd guess 0-0 :P

Comment: Re Hint 2: Rio de Janeiro to Brasilia?

Comment: Nice puzzle idea!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The *Greece - Mexico* result is a complete blow out:

> **1-6**

The hints gave it away for me:

> "*countries' names in uppercase*" hinted at the country **capitals**, and
>  "*BRAZIL-BELGIUM, ... used to be 0-1*" reinforced that (Brazil's capital was Rio up until 1960, when it changed to Brasilia)

So, the trick is that the scores are based on:

> the number of characters that are the same, and in the same location between a country and its capital. Meaning that the specific pairing is just a red herring, since each individual country is evaluated in isolation.

The full list explained:

> ```
> NETHERLANDS     FINLAND
> amstERdAm       helsiNki      3−1
>
> JAPAN           IRAQ
> tokyo           baghdad       0−0
>
> RUSSIA          INDONESIA
> moScow          jakarta       1−0
>
> AUSTRALIA       CHINA
> canberra        beIjing       0−1
>
> CANADA          CUBA
> ottAwA          havAna        2−1
>
> SWITZERLAND     FRANCE
> bern            paris         0−0
>
> MADAGASCAR      EGYPT
> antAnAnarivo    cairo         2−0
>
> BRAZIL          BELGIUM
> BRAsILia        Brussels      5−1
> rio de janeiro  Brussels     (0-1)
>
> IRELAND         GERMANY
> dubLiN          bERliN        2−3
>
> ALGERIA         COLOMBIA
> ALGiers         bOgOta        3−2
>
> GREECE          MEXICO
> athEns          MEXICO city   1-6
> ```

Comment: Gosh darn it, I was so close. I got as far as your 2nd spoilertag (see my comment on the question), but I tried looking at the number of letters shared between the capitals in each pair (Dublin-Berlin etc.) and didn't get as far as your final realisation. +1.