# Pathetic Neighbor!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

Mr. Heisenberg recently moved next to my apartment. An old and needy person I say. Disgusted with the continuous taps and noises on my door I decided to leave the apartment. Well, are you thinking about the taps and noises? Well, I will explain it with some cases I faced in a day -

It was an early morning when I heard someone banging my door and some kind of crappy sounds. Irritated, I went running

> *BOOM KNOCK KNOCK KNOCK*. I opened the door. It was the old man. With a Ball in his hand he asked - "Can you please replace one of this with one of your Cube?" I said "What? I do not have any cube sorry."

5 minutes later there was a bang again -

> *BOOM KNOCK KNOCK*. I opened the door. And there he was again. With a Durian in his hand he asked - "Can you please replace one of this with one of your Oranges" I said "What? I do not have any oranges sorry"

And 5 minutes later...

> *"BOOM BOOM KNOCK"* I opened the door. And there he was again. With a Guava in his hand he asked -"Can you please replace one of this with one of your Fig?" I said "What? I do not have any figs sorry."

And again 5 minutes later -

> *"BOOM BOOM KNOCK"* I opened the door. And there he was again. With a Ximenia  in his hand he asked -"Can you please replace one of this with one of your Eggs?" I said "What? I do not have any eggs sorry."

And again ... This time it was

> *"BOOM KNOCK KNOCK BOOM"* I didn't opened this time.

A few minutes back it banged again -

> *"BOOM KNOCK KNOCK BOOM"*

Troubled and disgusted, I opened the door ferociously. The old man was right there. I asked him what now? Making a sad face he handed me a note and went back. I was confused with the stuff he wrote -

> Friend, this would have never happened. It was just that Night time scares me. Dragons arrive in my nightmares. Many other insane things appear as well. Owls flying all around me. Rattle Snakes hissing those scary sounds. Elephants running around wanting to kill me. Ultimately Son, I needed something from you. Never mind, Good night. Bye AND take Kare

Well, I can understand he is an old man and hence could have made the typo. But wait, what was he looking for? I went back to letter and remember all the things he said and all the things he did. Oh no! He just wanted that little something.

It was the first time when I googled about Mr. Heisenberg and found that he was an amazing Puzzler. How bad of me. I solved the puzzle within minutes and gave him what he needed.

**Can you tell me what he needed?**

**Note - Block quotes are enough to solve the puzzle.**

Comment: Hah! I couldn't figure the puzzle but I know where the old man lives. Durian+Guava = most likely Indonesia or Malaysia. Maybe broader south-east Asia. Checking the map for Durian... Or India, maybe even Australia.  Aah... Never mind.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe mr. Heisenberg just needed some

> **coffee** because he didn't want to fall asleep (because of the nightmares)

First thing I spotted is the final note of the old man:

> Taking uppercase letters renders "**FINDMORSEUSINGBANDK**" which may be "**Find Morse using b and k**" which suggests the Morse code

The "b and k" refers to:

> **B**OOM and **K**NOCK of course :)

Using the

> Morse code

on the "BOOM KNOCK" part gives us

> If BOOM is "-" and KNOCK is "." we have
>  "-... -.. --. --. -..- -..-" which is **bdggxx**

Mr. Heisenberg asked us to replace

> **B**all for **C**ube
>  **D**urian for **O**range
>  **G**uava for **F**ig
>  **G**uava for **F**ig
>  **X**imenia for **E**ggs
>  **X**imenia for **E**ggs

Which changes the

> **bdggxx** into **coffee**

Comment: Good +1. I made a little edit. You can edit your answer. You are on track.

Comment: Comment after your update - No, nothing of knowledge or lateral thinking or trivia here. As noted - Only the block quote matters. Rest is just a part of story building.

Comment: Glad you figured out the "B And K" part. A big green tick, Hope you liked it!   :)

Comment: Sure. Not too hard, but also not obvious. Also the consistency of the plot made it even more enjoyable. Good job :)

Comment: Oh my difficult ones are really bad ones! :D I chose easier than badder! ;)